# How to track inputs on a form with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've alredy achieve that by doing:

```
$('#myforn:input').on("input", myMethod);
```

However, this method is not supported IE.

Another approach is proposed in other topics is something like this:

```
        $('#myForm').on('propertychange input', function(ev){
        myMethod()
    });
```

Which doesn't work when there is input on my form neither.

So how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
$('#myForm').on('change', 'input', function () {
  console.log(this, ' input was changed.')
});
```

If you also have `textarea` or `select` inputs, your code should use `input, textarea, select`:

```
$('#myForm').on('change', 'input, textarea, select', function () {
  console.log(this, ' input was changed.')
});
```

Some inputs (like textareas) send the `change` notification only when they lose focus. You may want to use the `keyup`, `keydown` or `keypress` events too:

```
$('#myForm').on('change keyup keydown keypress', 'input, textarea, select', function () {
  console.log(this, ' input was changed.')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please always specify which version(s) of IE you're testing with, and also the version of jQuery.

These details are important because jQuery **does** fully support IE, so your code should work the same in IE as any other browser. If it doesn't then here are a few things to check:

- You may be using a version of jQuery that is incompatible with your IE version. If you need to support IE8 or earlier, then you must use jQuery v1.x. jQuery v2 and v3 only support newer IE versions.
- Check whether IE is rendering the page in Quirks mode. This will break compatibility with jQuery. Fix the page so that it uses standards mode.